# Converter data com deslocamento

Tags: javascript

Quero fazer um deslocamento da hora, ou seja adicionar ou subtrair a hora. O problema é se a hora é 24, e o deslocamento 1, a hora final vai ser 25. O mesmo caso para se a hora for 0, e deslocamento -1, o resultado vai ser -1. Como posso resolver isso?

```
var d = new Date();
var hora_deslocamento = 2
console.log(d.getHours()+hora_deslocamento);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode calcular utilizando Unix Timestamp que torna isso bem simples, exemplo:

```
function horasDeslocamento(date, horas){
    return new Date(date.getTime() + (horas * 60 * 60 * 1e3));
}
```

Agora você pode utilizar da seguinte maneira:

```
var d = new Date();
console.log(horasDeslocalmento(d, +2));
```

Podendo também usar subtração.

Explicação da operação aritmética:

Número de horas, multiplicado por 60 (referente aos minutos), multiplicado por 60 (referente aos segundos), multiplicado 10 elevado a 3 (1000) referente aos milissegundos.

O resultado desta operação é somado ao valor em UNIX Timestamp do seu objeto de data e retorna um novo objeto inicializado na posição que você deseja.